# "Already connected" Exception when running jersey application inside docker container

Tags: jakarta-ee, docker, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to dockerize a jersey application which acts both as a REST server and client. The application seems to behave differently when running inside a docker container.

I am able to perform a request to a non-dockerized service (A). The problem occurs when I try to perform a request on another non-dockerized REST server (B), using, in both cases, JAX-RS client API:

```
// common code - for contacting both A & B services
private static final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonFeature.class);  

// inside the method called for each request
WebTarget target = client.target(location);
// for each query param : target = target.queryParam(..);
logger.info("This is logged successfully");
Response resp = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).method(method, Entity.json(payloadBean));
logger.info("This is NOT logged for B service");
```

At this point I am getting a `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected` ... `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected`

I use a single Dockerfile where I set up oracle-java-8 and (Tomcat or Jetty), in the exact same way I did on the host before docker where everything works fine!

There is no SSL involved for sure.

Running my app on the same VM with B service produces the same behavior.

Service A is jersey, while B is django, but that shouldn't be relative to the problem since they are both REST services.

Any idea on how I could debug this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for the spam, as it turned out it was a very stupid mistake:

```
service A location was an IP address
service B location was an uknown dns name to the container
```

Thus passing `--add-host B_fqdn:B_internal_IP` to `docker run` solved the issue

Comment: Just in case helps someone: I had a similar problem, but in my case both services were in the same container, but *they didn't know*, so adding the extra host solved it.